# Using captured type to define a new instance

Tags: typescript

```
class NewInstanceOfClass {
    public static Make<N>(instance:N):void {
        return (new N()); //Cannot find name 'N'.
    }
}
```

This may be too simple an example, but I would like to be able to use captured type data to create a new instance of the exact class the instance belonged to. Is that possible in TS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript implements generics using type erasure, so `new N()` will not work because N is unknown at runtime. Given your code, you have two options:

You can either pass in a constructor:

```
public static Make<N>(classCtor:new ()=> N) : N {
    return new classCtor(); 
}
Make(SomeClass)
```

Why do we need the `new` in front of the function type: While the constructor is a function, it is a special function that can build an object, can be invoked with the `new` operator. The specification defines such functions as [constructor literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#389-constructor-type-literals)

Or you can get the constructor of the class if you have an instance of the type using the `constructor` built-in property

```
public static Make2<N>(instance: N) : N {
    let classCtor: new ()=> N = instance.constructor as any;
    return new classCtor(); 
}
Make2(new SomeClass())
```

Comment: Missing `new` in second example - `new instance.constructor();`

Comment: Can you explain why you use the 'new' keyword in the type of classCtor in the first example? Isn't the constructor itself just a function ()=>N ? I can't find this type of usage anywhere in the handbook.

Comment: Also, in second example, I think Aleksey is correct about missing 'new' but when included I get an error: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yes the `new` was missing, my bad, fixed it.

Comment: @joshstrike Added link to the spec about constructor literal types, it might be that this is a more advanced topic and wasn't included I the handbook,

Answer (score 1):

> return (new N()); //Cannot find name 'N'.

You need to return `instance` as `N` is not in the variable declaration space

## Fix : General idea

```
class NewInstanceOfClass {
    public static Make<N>(instance:N):void {
        return (new instance()); 
    }
}
```

## More

Declaration spaces https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

Comment: Is there any way to get the type N as a string, and evaluate the string as a class name you want to construct? This is a very simple example but what I really want to do is be able to retrieve static variables from different classes. For that I need to know the name of the class I'm passing in, or somehow have access to its static namespace.